# Check connected client to personal hotspot using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to check the client connected to a personal hotspot using flutter?
Like I have created a hotspot and want to see who is connected to the personal hotspot

Comment: Please check this, it may help : https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot

Comment: i've try that package and found this error MissingPluginException : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getClientList on channel wifi_iot) when i'm tryin to gect connected client. @AVEbrahimi